# Sed: Change case of substitution group

Tags: regex, sed, unix

How can I change the case of a matching group from lower to uppercase with sed Unix command?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 23):

Surround your matching pattern in parentheses ie: \(pattern\) and then use \U\1 as the replacement text.  \1 is the matching pattern and \U forces uppercase.

```
echo abcdef | sed -e 's/\(abc\)/\U\1/'
```

Comment: [Relevant section of the sed documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command).

Comment: This helped me with partially lower-casing a line of text, where a colon marked the start of the text to be lower-cased: `s#\(^.*:\)\(.*\)#\1\L\2#`

Comment: Thanks @IanMackinnon sure helped to see the `\E` to end the conversion as `\U`/`L` does not apply just to the capture group

Answer (score 3):

Run it through tr?

Just kidding. You can use the [y///](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-49) transform to do case changes. It's not terribly convenient, but it's functional. If your transform gets too complex, you may want to consider escalating to perl.

Comment: Why specifically Perl?

Comment: Because perl was designed specifically for this kind of thing, and does one-liner scripts well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a sed question just wanted to point out there are several ways to do that function. awk is a tool that was made for text wrangling and in some cases is easier to use. In my opinion this is one of these times:

```
#!/bin/sh
INFO="This is a test"
ALLCAPS=`echo $INFO | awk '{print toupper($0)}'`
echo $ALLCAPS
```

Yields: THIS IS A TEST